# how to put inline image css in ghost-blog?

Tags: css, ghost-blog, handlebarshelper

I know this is very basic query, but I really need your help.

I am new to ghost, and use CSS' `background-image:url` property.

Since, I can't use ghost helpers in a css file, I have to put inline css in hbs file.

I am trying to do it this way, but no luck.

```
<div class="post-image" id="post-image" style='background: url("{{#if image}}{{/if}}")'>
    <a href="{{url}}"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: i found the solution. I was just doing it {{image}} between the if image loop

Comment: Great, you should answer your own question so it helps others who might have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way it should work:

```
{{#if image}}
<div class="post-image" id="post-image" style="background: url({{image}})">
    <a href="{{url}}"></a>
</div>
{{/if}}
```